# How to Join My Custom table to catalog search in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch

I have my own custom table with FK of product id and my own custom sku

when customer search the product it should also be searched from my custom sku of custom table along with default search

how to do it in M2

Comment: Join your custom table data with search collection.

Comment: all that is in M1,  please share M2 code , and also its not about Join  even the searched word should also be matched if that exists in my custom table how to do that

Comment: Can you please elaborate about the TableMapper and Match and show the example code of custom table mapping?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/144009)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the solution

1. add or map the table in `TableMapper` (`Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\TableMapper`)
2. Write a plugin for search map (`Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match`)

Comment: Can you show example code please?